# How do I upload .whl files to a custom PyPI server without using setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a directory full of `.whl` files generated with [venv-update](https://github.com/Yelp/venv-update), I would like to upload them to my [pypicloud](https://github.com/mathcamp/pypicloud) server.

Is there an easy way of doing it?